# Return error information from API when using Next-auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

Is it possible to allow next-auth to return errors from an API and pass them through from the client-side?

As an example, the API is returning specifically if the user's email or password is incorrect. On our mobile app, this is working great. Though on the website, we're using Next-auth. Using the credentials example from the documentation, it would be great to change the return value to an object.

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
    name: "Credentials",
 
    credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" }
    },
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
      const user = { id: 1, name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" }

      if (user) {
        // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
        return user
      } else {
        // Return an object that will pass error information through to the client-side.
        return { errors: user.errors, status: false }
      }
    }
  })
]
```

Please do let me know if there is another post that relates to this one as I'm unable to find it online.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes this should allow you to do that, though in the credential, when passing the values to the next auth, add a `redirect:false`

You can find the documentation [here](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option)

Your sign in method will therefore look like this.

```
signIn('credentials', { redirect: false, username:'username', password: 'password' })
```

Your code can look like this

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
    name: "Credentials",
 
    credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" }
    },
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
      const user = { id: 1, name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" }

      if (user) {
        // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
        return user
      } else {
        // Return an object that will pass error information through to the client-side.
        throw new Error( JSON.stringify({ errors: user.errors, status: false }))
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: This seems to have worked a treat. Thanks!

Comment: is there a better way?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you @obed-amoasi

Answer (score 1):

I managed to return the correct error information by using a promise with a catch statement in the authorize function:

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "example@example.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials: any) {
        // console.log(credentials);
        const { user, jwt } = await axios
          .post(`http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local`, {
            identifier: credentials.email,
            password: credentials.password,
          })
          .then(({ data }) => {
            return data;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw new Error(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
          });

        return { jwt, ...user };
      },
    }),
  ],
};
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The next-auth error is of type string, so you need to stringify it as JSON, then turn it back into an object from the client side.